# How to repair windows 7 explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, repair

Ok this is the case. Yesterday I tried to install theme in unfortunately i didnt make the backup of explorer.exe And the tool i used for Theme Installer for Window. That is available across internet and widely used. I always make the backup of the files which are patched.

Now whenever I try to start windows it says that explorer.exe is not starting. But windows automatically make a backup of Explorer.exe and name something explorer-back.exe. So i renamed the backup explorer to explorer.exe and restarted the windows but it is not working.

Any idea how to solve this issue. Please note Explorer is not running means NO GUI only thing is working is Task Manager and I can run cmd in NORMAL USER MODE

Comment: according to this - just a few people saying so - installing a theme shouldn't replace any exe or dll, especially not explorer.exe http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/themes-should-i-replace-the-file-explorerexe/6e4ed105-1f4a-42f6-b92c-d2339811eac5  how about you try copying an explorer.exe from another working windows 7 computer?

Comment: sorry dear copying explorer.exe didnt worked. Any other Idea.

Comment: In the west males don't call each other dear and generally don't greet each other with kisses, or wear a skirt(thawb). You thought explorer.exe had been changed and that had caused it, but I suppose it hadn't. You could try a Windows 7 repair installation.

Comment: Hahahhaha thanks for telling me about this dear thing . I solved the issue by running sfc /scannow

Comment: You could post that as your answer and accept it(accept your own answer).

Comment: Why were you messing with system files in the first place?

Comment: @kinokijuf  It looks like something some people do sometimes when installing new (3rd party I suppose) themes. And he must've done it    http://windows7themes.net/how-to-replace-explorer-exe-in-windows-7.html         http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/46312-replace-explorer-exe-another.html     http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/13560-A-way-To-replace-Explorer-exe

Comment: Hahahahha Habit my friend habit

Comment: @kinokijuf   You're right that Windows 7 booted off a disc doesn't have a repair installation. The "Upgrade"(repair installation) option gives an error message straight away

Answer (score 0):

Solved by running sfc /scannow.

- First I launched the Task Manager using ALT+CTRL+DEL.
- Then from select New Task and browse to C:\Windows\System32 and Right
  click and select Run as Administrator.
- Then used command to sfc /scannow

Now it will take some minutes to solve the issue after that just restart the pc using **shutdown  /rf** command and here you go you got Explorer back.